# 'Kiss rocks'? Why would anyone want to kiss rocks?

Tags: usage

A joke from “Buffy” (S3E6):

A huge inscription is spray-painted on the lockers “Kiss rocks”. Willow says: “   "Kiss rocks"? Why would anyone want to kiss... Oh, wait. I get it.”

Well, I don’t get it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"[KISS](https://www.kissonline.com/)" is a rock band.  To "rock" is to be excellent at performing rock music. (or by extension, to be excellent in general).

So this is saying "The Rock band "KISS" are excellent".

Comment: to rock is be cool, generally.

Comment: Compare with 'sucks', which means the opposite.